# Can't install PyDev eclipse plugin

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, installation, pydev

I am having the following errors when I try and install PyDev on eclipse indigo

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java,     
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.4.1.201403181715.
Error reading signed     
content:C:\Users\Md\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3601630487889967036.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:     C:\Users\Md\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3601630487889967036.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.4.1.201403181715.
```

It goes on with similar error log for a fairly long list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason not using latest eclipse version?Add the steps how you are installing the **Pydev**

Comment: Was told indigo would be the best version to work with android sdk

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the PyDev version is the same as your installed Python version.
so if you have `Python 2.7` installed, `PyDev 3` will give you errors like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Eclipse -> Go to Help -> Install New Software...
2. Type the following URL on Work with text field:
   http://pydev.org/updates
3. Check and click Next button
4. Proceed next steps by the guidance of eclipse
5. After successful installation: Go to Window | Preferences -- PyDev is enlisted at the left side